# Open multiple webview from single activity

Tags: android

We have a requirement where we want multiple webview instance to be open from same application.

E.g Android app1 should open page1.html in first webview instance and page2.html in second webview instance. When page2.html is started page1.html webview should go in background.

Is this possible in Android? Is yes, Can you please provide sample code or link which talks in details as how this requirement can be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void callwebtwo(){
            loadweb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.loadweb);
            loadweb2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.loadweb2);
            loadweb2.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            loadweb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            loadweb2.loadUrl("http://www.google.co.in/");
            loadweb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    Log.i("shouldOverrideUrlLoading", url.toString());
                    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    Log.i("onPageFinished", url.toString());
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                    Log.i("onPageStarted", url.toString());
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                }

                }

            });
            loadweb2.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    Log.i("shouldOverrideUrlLoading", url.toString());
                    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    Log.i("onPageFinished", url.toString());
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                    Log.i("onPageStarted", url.toString());
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                }



            });

}
```

instance of the both web is different so it will work and perform seperatly..
i gvn ans whtever i cn understand frm ur quest.

Comment: Thanks user1140237, I will try it out and if it works I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it in android.

Create seperate activities for both and when you load page2 in second webview instance then obvisouly page1 webview instance will be in back of second and when you press back from page2 then page1 will be infront.